# Largest Dimensional Matrix

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica, sparse-matrix, large-data

What is the current state-of-the-art method for the handling of large dimensional matrices and how large dimension of a square matrix can it handle?

Basically, I'm trying to work with 2^100 dimensional square matrix but finding it difficult to go beyond 2^15 or so even when I choose to work with sparse matrices (`SparceMatrix` function in Mathematica). So, I'm looking for techniques which can help me do the job. I can see a physics research [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.03416) in which the authors have went up to 2^200 dimensional square matrix and found it's eigenvalues & eigenfunctions as well.

Comment: Your main constraint is going to be the integer size of your indices - you'll need to use a non-standard (int256?) type, and I don't know if there's a lot of built packages or software that can handle that. If you're willing to write in C you should be able to do it.

Comment: To clarify, the limit you're hitting now is that in a signed int32, you'll overflow when your indices (row and column positions) go past 2^31. (And if mathematica uses signed int16s, your limit is 2^15).

Comment: @CJR Yes, I understand that. But the issue is that the authors of the paper mentioned in the question somehow went to 2^200 by some method which is absolutely baffling to me and they don't even mention how they did that!

Comment: I would assume that they either used a super-long integer for their indices (e.g. a signed int256 would let you get to 2^255 rows & columns) or they used a indexed twiced If you consider a 2^63 x 2^63 matrix where each element is itself a 2^63 x 2^63 matrix you can index everything with int64s but still have a 2^126 x 2^126 matrix.  Difficult to do unless you're writing your analysis code yourself in something like C.

Comment: Suppose your matrix is so sparse that it is just a diagonal of 2^100 64-bit decimals. That makes addition and multiplication and maybe even eigen values easy to do.
That takes 10^18 10-terabyte hard drives to store each of your two matricies.
At 6 watts per hard drive that takes 5*10^10 terawatt hours per year for each matrix.
The entire U.S. power consumption for all of 2020 was 3802 terawatt hours. Check all these calculations VERY carefully to make certain I haven't made a mistake.